# Tweepy query doesn't retrieve all keywords / never finishes results for one day

Tags: python, loops, twitter, keyword, tweepy

I'm trying to retrieve all tweets from a fixed list of cryptocurrencies but the query is completely broken. When I look for all the terms at once, the total number of tweets are significantly lower than if I look for just 1 or 2 keywords.

But even if I get all the results, there is a second problem: the script never finishes its execution. The code was supposed to look for all the tweets at the day before yesterday, getting the data from 23:59:59 and going backwards until 00:00:00, when it should stop.

Instead, it does start at 23:59:59 but ends on a loop, going back to this time and retrieving the same tweets. Sometimes it reaches 00:00:00 but usually gets to a random time (e.g. 14:23:57, 09:47:12) before starting over 23:59:59 again, depending on the amount of tweets for that particular day.

This is my code (I'm using python 3.6):

```
import tweepy
import csv
import datetime
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from datetime import timedelta

consumer_key = 'XXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXX'
access_token = 'XXX'
access_secret = 'XXX'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)  

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

today_string = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d%b%Y')
d1 = (datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
d2 = (datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(days=2)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

csvFile = open('cryptos' + today_string + '.csv', 'w+')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

# This is the regular query
query = 'Ethereum OR Cardano OR #XVG OR $XVG OR #Verge' \
        '#ADA OR $ADA OR $EOS OR #EOS #ETH OR $ETH OR' \
        '#XEM OR $NEM OR MaidSafeCoin OR Zcash OR Zcoin' \
        '#ZEC OR $XZC OR #MAID OR $MAID OR Monero OR #XMR OR $XMR'
# When I test with just two terms (an example below) the results are significantly higher 
#query = "#XVG OR $XVG"

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=query  ,count=100,
                       since=d2, until=d1, lang="en").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.user.name, tweet.text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.user.screen_name, 
                          tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])

csvFile.close()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!